# Laptop is very slow even after reformat

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, performance, acer-aspire

I have a laptop (Asus Aspire A515-51G). When I first purchased it ran fairly fast but is now super slow (slow to start the OS, slow to open applications, slow to run applications).

My first fix attempt was to free up HDD space, it has a 1TB HDD which is at least half empty, so it shouldn't be an issue there.

Next I figured it could be an OS issue, I re-installed Windows but it was still slow, so I installed Fedora Linux which is also running super slow.

The computer came with 4GB memory, which I had upgraded by adding a 16GB memory stick. I tried removing that to see if it was an issue with the memory but it was still just as slow.

I then tried updating the bios to the latest version, but that didn't help either.

So I am guessing it is an issue with either the Hard-drive or motherboard? HDD should be easy enough to replace if it is the issue, but is they a way I can find out if that is the issue before buying a new one?

Comment: It is unlikely to be a main board issue. Is your hard drive an SSD?

Comment: No, it's not SSD.

Comment: It could be many things. One of the potential reason is HDD problems, which is why I suspect that music2myear asked if it was HDD or SSD.  In which case I expect it to log S.M.A.R.T. errors.  And if that is the case I also expect a USB booted OS (with the HDD not mounted) to run fast.   If that is the case, great (as in, problem identified). If that is not the case then it could be something else. e.g. dirt clogging the heatsink, heatsink detached, CPU fan died... resulting in thermal throtling.

Comment: Besides what's been suggested I cannot add anything. If something is wrong you need to identify it and solve it. But as far as a general rule, putting an SSD in your computer is a good way to speed it up in pretty substantial ways.